# Callable class giving error: doPing is not abstract and does not override abstract method call()?

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

I seem to be getting the above error when trying to make a callable class. I have searched for the reason but can't seem to find anything. NetBeans gives me a few options to make things abstract but I'm new to this and I'd rather find out why something is happening. Can anyone shed light on this?

```
public class doPing implements Callable<String>{

    public String call(String IPtoPing) throws Exception{

        String pingOutput = null;

        //gets IP address and places into new IP object
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(IPtoPing);
        //finds if IP is reachable or not. a timeout timer of 3000 milliseconds is set.
        //Results can vary depending on permissions so cmd method of doing this has also been added as backup
        boolean reachable = IPAddress.isReachable(1400);

        if (reachable){
              pingOutput = IPtoPing + " is reachable.\n";
        }else{
            //runs ping command once on the IP address in CMD
            Process ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping " + IPtoPing + " -n 1 -w 300");
            //reads input from command line
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ping.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            int lineCount = 0;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //increase line count to find part of command prompt output that we want
                lineCount++;
                //when line count is 3 print result
                if (lineCount == 3){
                    pingOutput = "Ping to " + IPtoPing + ": " + line + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        return pingOutput;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the `call` method has an argument: it does not override the `call` method of the `Callable` interface - It should look like:

```
public String call() throws Exception{ //not public String call(String IPtoPing)

}
```

If you are using Java 6+, it is good practice ot use the `Override` annotation, which can help spot wrong method signatures (in this case you already got a compilation error):

```
@Override
public String call() throws Exception{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'doPing' class is defined as `implements Callable<String>`.  This means that it should implement the `call()` method that *does not take any arguments*.  Here's the definition of `Callable`:

```
public interface Callable<V> {
    V call() throws Exception;
}
```

You will need to remove the `String IPtoPing` argument if you want `doPing` to be `Callable`:

```
public class doPing implements Callable<String> {
     // you need to define this method with no arguments to satisfy Callable
     public String call() throws Exception {
         ...
     }
     // this method does not satisfy Callable because of the IPtoPing argument
     public String call(String IPtoPing) throws Exception {
         ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface requires you have a `call()` method. However your method is
 `call(String ipToPing)`.

Consider adding a `setIpToPing(String ip)` method to set the correct ip.

I.e.

```
doPing myCallable = new doPing();//Note doPing should be called DoPing to keep in the java naming standards.
myCallable.setIpToString(ip);//Simple setter which stores ip in myCallable
myCallable.call();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. much appreciated. IPtoPing is a variable within my main method in a different class so how would I be able to carry this variable over to call()?

Comment: @user1286779 No problem. I've added an example.